# How do I run a shell script on multiple CGE machines concurrently?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have multiple Linux GCE machines and there's a bash script I want to run on some of them from time to time. Right now I'm connecting manually to each machine separately in order to run the script.
How do I run the script on several machines concurrently without connecting to each machine individually each time? How do I configure on which machines it should run?

Answer (score 1):

you can use csshx to ssh into multiple servers at once. Once logged in into servers, you can execute script as per your need. you can follow this [link](https://medium.com/@joantolos/cluster-ssh-tool-using-macos-a66930eeada6) to install it on mac.

Other alternative could be that you schedule a cronjob at all servers so they will run at specific time. you can edit these multiple cronjobs using csshx.

Answer (score 0):

Try [fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/). You can write simple scripts in Python that you can run on multiple hosts (which you will need SSH access to).